# Messages see chat history?

Tags: macos, messages

I am a little confused, I am using Messages but after like 20 messages the previous messages disappear. How can I increase it or go back and look at previous messages?

Answer (score 1):

Messages are saved in the User ~Library/Messages folder on your computer, messages from any device. Attachments too. This makes for a very nice backup and reference that can, in addition, be easily read with QuickLook.

Answer (score 0):

They're loaded automatically when scroll to the top of the conversation. If nothing is loading it's because there is probably no history for this conversation.